# How to fill expression (from another dataset) with tablix row data in Report Builder?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, expression, reportbuilder

I am trying to create a report with Report Builder where I have a list of data coming from a dataset (SQL View). The column Test, does not contain data from this dataset, but is an expression to get the values from another dataset.

The expression is: `=Sum(Fields!COUNT.Value, "TestDataset")`

I want to fill the Test column with the count using the Unique ID (1st column) for that row, meaning that each row would have different count numbers in the Test column. Basically, I want the SQL where clause to be the Unique ID for each row.

This is the list showing if no parameters are filled:

[image: no parameters are filled]

Empty parameters:

[image: Empty parameters]

Then I can use the Unique ID parameter to search for a specific ID:

[image: specific ID search]

Result of the specific unique ID search - but as you can see test is not updating as it is refering to the "Identity UID" parameter that is left empty:

[image: Result of the specific unique ID search]

Filling out the "Identity UID" field, will then trigger that expression above and fill out the number.

[image: IUID parameter]

Same result for all rows, as it is not adjusting to the data in the row but only in the parameter. So it is just repeating.

[image]

The reason it is 2 different datasets is that data is from 2 different tables and I am not aware of how I can join the TestDataset (`Count(*)`) with the other SQL View dataset.

[image]

I also looked at `LookupSet` but I do not have a field to join on when using Count(*).

I am using T-SQL (SSMS / SSRS).

Expression SQL from first dataset:

```
"SELECT TOP " & Parameters!MaxRows.Value & " ObjectID,UID,Name,BLABLA... "
& ",(SELECT Count(*)" -- SUBQUERY
& " FROM INT_RA "
& " Where IdentityUID like '%' + @UID + '%'"
& " AND (AccountObjectID = -2 OR Account_IdentityJoinConfirmState like '%Confirmed%')"
& " AND GETUTCDATE() BETWEEN EffectiveTime AND ExpirationTime"
& " Group By IdentityUID)" -- END SUBQUERY
& " FROM AUD_IDENTITY
& " WHERE "
& IIF(Parameters!UID.Value = Nothing, "", " AND UID like '%' + @UID + '%'")
& "... lots of where clauses";
```

Comment: So for that `TestDataset`, you need to add the `Unique ID` in that dataset and `Group By` that column. Then you can do the LookupSet with the `Unique ID`.

Comment: Thanks. You mean I need to add UID as a parameter like this `Group By @UID` even though I am using `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM`?

Comment: `Select Unique_ID, Count(1) From table Group By Unique_ID` This should be the TestDataset. You need the ID in that dataset to reference the main dataset of the report.

Comment: Can you show the 2 queries that you are using to get the 2 different datasets?

Comment: `The reason it is 2 different datasets is that data is from 2 different tables and I am not aware of how I can join the TestDataset (Count(*)) with the other SQL View dataset.` In the first query you can put a subquery as a column to get the count, thus only using 1 query.

Comment: I tried to add the subquery and posted the code above. I am receiving the following error now after adding the `Group By IdentityUID`Cannot read the next data row for the dataset Identity. (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)
 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: If I try your first suggestion with keeping 2 datasets and changing the `TestDataset` then I am receiving `"Must declare the scalar variable "@UID"`. I am using the same subquery as in my post, except I added `IdentityUID` and `Count(1)` and `Group By IdentityUID`.

Comment: Change `Where IdentityUID like '%' + @UID + '%'"` to `Where IdentityUID = AUD_IDENTITY.UID` 

You need to tie the subquery to the outer query by the UID.